# В Django по книге Дронова при регистрации отправляется письмо активации, но при переходе по ссылке происходит ошибка URL, как быть?

Tags: django, django-urls

view

```
def user_activate(request, sign):
    try:
        username = signer.unsign(sign)
    except BadSignature:
        return render(request, 'main/bad_signature.html')
    user = get_object_or_404(AdvUser, username=username)
    if user.is_activated:
        return render(request, 'main/user_is_activated.html')
    else:
        user.is_active = True
        user.is_activated = True
        user.save()
    return render(request, 'main/activation_done.html')
```

forms

```
        def clean_password1(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']
        try:
            password_validation.validate_password(password1)
        except forms.ValidationError as error:
            self.add_error('password1', error)
        return password1

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']
        password2 = self.cleaned_data['password2']
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            errors = {'password2': ValidationError(
                'Введенные пароли не совпадают', code='password_mismatch')}
            raise ValidationError(errors)
```

urls

```
app_name = 'main'
urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/register/activate/<str:sign>/', user_activate, name='register_activate'),
    path('accounts/logout/', BBLogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('accounts/profile/change', ChangeUserInfoView.as_view(), name='profile_change'),
    path('', index, name='index'),
    path('<str:page>/', other_page, name='other'),
    path('accounts/register/done/', RegisterDoneView.as_view(), name='register_done'),
    path('accounts/register/', RegisterUserView.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('accounts/login/', BBLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('accounts/profile/', profile, name='profile'),
    path('accounts/password/change/', BBPasswordChangeView.as_view(), name='password_change'),
]
```

apps

```
user_registered = Signal()


def user_registered_dispatcher(sender, **kwargs):
    send_activation_notification(kwargs['instance'])


user_registered.connect(user_registered_dispatcher)
```

utilities

```
signer = Signer()


def send_activation_notification(user):
    if ALLOWED_HOSTS:
        host = 'http://' + ALLOWED_HOSTS[0]
    else:
        host = 'http://localhost:8000'
    context = {'user': user, 'host': host, 'sign': signer.sign(user.username)}
    subject = render_to_string('email/activation_letter_subject.text', context)
    body_text = render_to_string('email/activation_letter_body.text', context)
    user.email_user(subject, body_text)
```

Вот сама ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какая конкретно ошибка?

Comment: @andreymal добавил скрин

Comment: Ну, ошибка говорит о том, что AdvUser с указанным username в базе не нашёлся. Ну а почему его в базе нет — это уже вам виднее, наверное. Проверяйте код регистрации? Вызывать save не забыли?